# how to convert time according to User time zone without date php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, utc, php-carbon

I have a table in database named `USERSHIFTS` and it has  two `TIME` type columns along with other columns first one is it `start_time` and second one is `end_time` and both have `TIME datatype` . i am not allowed to change these columns types to `datetime or timestamp`. And also not allowed to create another column in table. Now my task is to display time that has been stored in `start_time` and `end_time` column  according to user `timezone` for example `UTC` `timezone` user should be able to time according to `UTC` timezone and Other timezone user should also be able to see this time according to his timezone .
Now question is how should i store time in database and in which timezone i should store time. And Final question is how should i display time according to different timezones.
i tried following code but you can see i have to deal with date in order to do this. And i dont want date .

```
 $s_time=date('Y-m-d '.$shift->start_time.'');
 $start_time = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $s_time, 'UTC');
 $e_time=date('Y-m-d '.$shift->end_time.'');


 $end_time = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $e_time, 'UTC');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This convert directly the date from the database to this what you want. In this function you convert time to the timezone time you want

```
$start_time = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $shift->start_time, 'UTC')->format('H:i:s');
$end_time = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $shift->end_time, 'UTC')->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing

Comment: Are the fields start_time and end_time existing?

Comment: yes and both have time stored in this format start time equal to  10:30:00 and end time equal to   16:30:00

Comment: Only time in this? No date?

Comment: yes only time no date is allowed as i mentioned above

Comment: Then remove 'Y-m-d '

Comment: It's best if you explain your answer, so that everyone can follow it..